# Is the zero vector in the definition of linear dependence arbritary?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

The definition of linear dependence according to wikipedia is

> The vectors in a subset $S=(v1,v2,...,vk)$ of a vector space $V$ are said to be linearly dependent, if there exist a finite number of distinct vectors $v1, v2, ..., vn$ in $S$ and scalars $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$, not all zero, such that
>    $ a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_k v_k = 0, $
>   where zero denotes the zero vector.

I was wondering if the zero vector in the definition of linear dependence is arbritary?

Thanks,
Jackson

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The "zero vector" is _the_ vector for which $\forall \vec{v} \in V: \vec{v} + \vec{0} = \vec{v}$ (the "zero" vector is the identity of addition).

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Is my question clearer now?

Comment: Are you asking the following question? "For a given vector space $V$, if we replaced the zero vector with a fixed vector $v_0$ in the definition of linear dependence, would the resulting definition be equivalent?"

Comment: Yes. For example would the definition change if the vector was all ones instead of zeros?

Comment: You talk about $a_1$ to $a_n$ and $v_1$ to $v_n$ but then it boils down to $a_k$ and $v_k$???

Comment: If ${\bf 0}$ and ${\bf 0}'$ are zero vectors, i.e. both  "neutral" with respect to addition, then ${\bf 0'}={\bf 0'}+{\bf 0}={\bf 0}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if it were, then we would have a very curious situation. Try replacing $0$ with some fixed vector $v_0 \ne 0$. Then the set $\{ 0 \}$ is independent, but the set $\{ v_0 \}$ isn't!

To make things worse: if you had two vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $\{ a, b, v_0 \}$ was independent in the standard sense, then the set $\{ \lambda a + \mu b \mid \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is independent, despite being a whole subspace!

EDIT: Maybe a specific example will help. Say we define "independent" to mean "there is a linear combination that sums to $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$. Then the set $\{ \langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle, \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle, \langle 1, 1, 0 \rangle \}$ is independent (no matter what combination you take, the $z$-component is zero, not one, so you can never get $ \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle $). But this is clearly silly, because one vector is the sum of the other two, and so whatever our definition is describing, it doesn't capture the notion of independence.

Comment: This is interesting! $\{0\}$ being independent isn't *too* wild, it's almost like we've shifted the origin (so it doesn't seem much crazier than $\{v_0\}$ being independent in the normal sense). The subspace of independent vectors made me think for a while about what's going on.

Comment: How do you know that the set of zero vectors is independent? Also I'm confused about your second part. Lastly, does it fit the definition? It seems like your answer is it fits it, but not so well where as @Nitin Madeshia says it does. Thanks.

Comment: It's independent because there's no linear combination of $\{ 0 \}$ that sums to $v_0$, because $\lambda \cdot 0 = 0 \ne v_0$. As for the second part, my point was: $a$, $b$, and all their linear combinations are independent, and that's not the kind of result you want. I don't think I understand your second question. Is that not the re-definition of "independent" that you wanted?

Comment: Essentially what I'm asking is does the $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+⋯+a_kv_k$ have to equal $0$ (the zero vector). Could it be equal to $[1, 1, 1]$ or $[1,2,3]$ instead? You might have answered that but I've just started to learn linear algebra and it's hard to understand because of my lack of experience with the subject. Read Nitin Madeshia's answer and see if that is correct because it seems as if yours and his are different.

Comment: No, if you change the definition like that, you don't get anything useful. See my edit. Lemme know if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response I understand now.

Comment: The reason I didn't understand was I was thinking only of vectors that take up $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of realizing vector could be dependent and only lie on a line.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you were aiming at. If there's two different ways to make a vector from linear combinations, then the set is dependent. The proof of this is easy: subtract the two combinations, and you'll get a non trivial combination that gives the zero vector. :)

Answer (score 1):

A set of vectors are **called** linearly dependent if at least one of them can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. Moving them all to one side we get that linear dependence is equivalent to the existence of a linear combination with one coefficient being $1$ that is the same as the zero vector. Since vector spaces are over fields, we can drop the requirement of one of the coefficients being $1$ and just require the linear combination to be non-zero (not all zero).

Comment: I'm asking if the vector on the righthand side (the zero vector) has to be zero for the definition to still be correct.

Comment: @JacksonH: My answer already answers that. You just move everything to one side. If you had a non-zero vector on the right, that too.

Comment: You're right I understand the derivation now. I haven't learned much abstract algebra but is the reason you can drop the requirement of being $1$ is because you can have a different identity than one in some number system?

Comment: No it is because if we have a non-zero linear combination, we can multiply it by some suitable element of the field to make one coefficient become $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand; it is not necessary that the vector on the right hand side be zero. The only necessary condition is that there exist a non-trivial representation of the the vector as a linear combination of the other vectors.

### Trivial Solution

a1v1+a2v2+.........+anvn=0 only if a1=a2=a3=......=an

Alternatively; there exist atleast one non-zero scalars (a1,a2,....,an) for the set to be linearly dependent. So, the RHS can be non-zero.